# 304 and no json response on deployed app on Heroku

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, heroku

I'm working on the React + Express + mongo project.

Everything works locally, but when I deployed project on heroku.com, a problem appeared with GET requests.

It returns 304 and instead of body JSON, i'm getting this error:

> To run this application, you need to enable JavaScript.

Instead of json response, I'm getting HTML response with this information about JS. In body I should get normal data JSON that I display on the page.
I will write again, everything WORKS locally ( i get 200 and json response), I don't know what's going on with this heroku.

I thought that problem is 304 code, so I used middleware that disables cache (no-cache), the result is 200, but there is still no body.

REQUEST ON CHROME NETWORK

```
GENERAL:
Request URL: MYURL.com/...
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: 34.255.19.16:443
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

RESPONSE HEADERS::
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 2366
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Fri, 01 Nov 2019 13:54:09 GMT
Etag: W/"93e-16e271de930"
Expires: 0
Last-Modified: Fri, 01 Nov 2019 13:18:22 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Server: Cowboy
Surrogate-Control: no-store
Via: 1.1 vegur
X-Powered-By: Express

REQUEST HEADERS:
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: pl-PL,pl;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IjVkYTZkNjZhYTExYWI5MTM3MDU1MTY2OCIsIm5hbWUiOiJGaWxpcCIsImlhdCI6MTU3MjYxNjQ0MiwiZXhwIjoxNTcyNjIwMDQyfQ.c4uPda0njISa3VWNX0kK5cPRVW2X6A3wBNnt5hc5N-k
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/json
Cookie: AUTHORIZATION_JWT=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IjVkYTZkNjZhYTExYWI5MTM3MDU1MTY2OCIsIm5hbWUiOiJGaWxpcCIsImlhdCI6MTU3MjYxNjQ0MiwiZXhwIjoxNTcyNjIwMDQyfQ.c4uPda0njISa3VWNX0kK5cPRVW2X6A3wBNnt5hc5N-k
Host: dashboard-pwa.herokuapp.com
Referer: https://dashboard-pwa.herokuapp.com/tickets/show/5dbb2310f67d543c84053a79
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.90 Safari/537.36
```

I want to get 200 with JSON body response.

Comment: Are you using create-react-app? If so, check out this issue https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/4438. It might help

Comment: Thanks, that helped me a lot :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

adam tropp thank you! It helped me a lot. It turns out that i had redirect to client index.html in wrong place, it should be placed after routes declaration, not before (just like I had before).

*file server.js:*

```js
app.use('/api/user', require('./routes/user'));

// For any request that doesn't
// match one above, send back React's index.html file.
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/client/build/index.html'));
});
```

Thanks, once again.